# How to do administer Puppet 4 using scripts

Tags: automation, puppet, puppet-enterprise

I have to automate puppet 4 administration. According to puppet 4 documentation there are major changes like
* introduce puppetserver
* Ruby / Rack puppetmaster services are deprecated and will be removed from puppet 5 onwards.

My query is how do i administer my puppetserver on Puppet 4 with scripts? would like to do things like :

- add/remove a class
- add/list a parameter to a class
- create/list groups and add node to it

**Edit:**

for instance consider these two use case:

- how to add a class, edit class param to a node
- list classes assigned to a node

Comment: This question is far, far too broad to answer.

Comment: hi @JohnBollinger for instance if I would like to classify a node/class to a group I am using Classifier REST api.. Is there a command line alternative for it??

Comment: John is completely correct. There are several pieces of software to do these things, including Puppet Enterprise itself. If you want to do scripts, then you should write them and ask for help if you get stuck. As it is, this question will probably be flagged.

Comment: @vivekIndia, if the question is simply how to use the REST API from the command line then you should say so, and apply appropriate tags.  As far as that goes, however, REST is HTTP-based, so I would look into a command-line HTTP client such as `curl` or `wget`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger basically i wanted to know a way to interact with puppet server from command line as an alternative to REST api. for instance in puppet 3 we used Rake but it does not seem to work on puppet 4 now.

Comment: I disagree with the earlier responses to this question. The user is correct when puppet makes such a major change and publishes nothing as tools to use with the new API, they've not only made life difficult for end users, but have further released control of the market space. The docs for the API are not IMO good enough. Is it that difficult to write your own tools? no, but for the price of a support contract one shouldn't have to.